# MSCharts "No http handler was found for request type 'GET'" error

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I tried to install MSCharts on my Win2008 server. 
It installed without problem. 
Then I wrote 

in config.

But when I'm trying to open page with charts it returned following error.
No http handler was found for request type 'GET'

Do you have any thougths about the problem?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is what you need for **ASP.NET 4.0 / IIS 7.5 on Windows 7**:

Your web.config must contain the following:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;" />
</appSettings>


<compilation targetFramework="4.0">
 <assemblies>
  <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
 </assemblies>
</compilation>

<system.webServer>

<handlers>
      <add name="ChartImg" verb="*" path="ChartImg.axd"  type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"  />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

You also need this at the top of your aspx page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 10):

Like [Danil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117102/mscharts-no-http-handler-was-found-for-request-type-get-error/2146247#2146247) said,  IIS7 requires that you put the handlers in

```
<system.webserver>
    <handlers>
```

Add the two lines below after the last add-in handles

```
<add name="ChartImg" verb="*" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler,     System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"  />
<add name="ReportViewer" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler,Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

Answer (score 9):

Solution was in web config. IIS7 required to write handlers inside system.webserver but not in the system.web. So I just move handler and add name attribute as it became required.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure this out for hours.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know anything about MSCharts, but I'd say try changing the AppPool for the app to 'Classic .NET AppPool'.

Alternatively, you may need to modify your web.config to add the handler in there. See [Rick Strahl's post here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/168221.aspx).

Comment: I can't use classic app pool, thanks for answer. I will study Rick Strahl's post.