# ASP.Net Charts in webforms works on local system and dont work on web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, webforms, mschart

I am using MS Charts 4.0 in asp.net 4.0 web form application to generates few charts. It works fine on local system with Windows 7,  IIS 7.5, Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.net 4.0 /FW 4.0.

When i upload the same on web server it generates the error 
**Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd.**

```
        <httpHandlers>
          <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers> 

      </system.web>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="Storage=file;Timeout=20;Url=~/tempImages/;" />
      </appSettings>

      <system.webServer>
 <!--       
        <handlers>
          <add name="ChartImg" path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"  />
        </handlers>
-->
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      </system.webServer>
```

After implementing couple of solution it still doesnt work. I tried to use handlers inside system.webserver as you can see it is commented in the code but it still doesn't work. If i upload teh same on different web server it works but on live server it doesn't work. Live server also has IIS 7.5, Framework 4.0 installed.

Can you please tell me if it has something to do with the webserver configuration rathen than the web.config file, Because same code works fine on local machine and mochahost shared hosting test account but not on the live server.

I tried following and related solution but none seems to work
[MSCharts "No http handler was found for request type 'GET'" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117102/mscharts-no-http-handler-was-found-for-request-type-get-error)

Answer (score 2):

On my live configuration, I actually have both HTTPHandlers and Handlers:

`<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>`

`<system.web>

<httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>`

But it also could be that you don't have the correct access to the `~/tempimages/` folder?